# Why can't I convert a lambda with a non-copyable class parameter to a std::function?

Tags: c++, lambda

Consider the code below which fails to compile:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <functional>

class t{
    std::mutex m;
};

std::function<void(t test)> func = [](t test) {return;};
```

The following error is generated :

> error: conversion from '<lambda(t)>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void(t)>' requested

Can you explain to me why this conversion is not working?

PS : live example here : https://godbolt.org/z/7se8crf41

Comment: a `std::mutex` is neither copy-able nor movable (which propagates to `t`), did you mean to use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` or maybe take `t` by reference instead?

Comment: @PeterT That fixes the issue, but how do you explain the error message?

Comment: I think `t` not being copyable nor movable is the root cause, but I dont see how that alone explains the error when you consider that `auto f = [](t test) {return;}; f({});` is ok

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number one of the requirements of `std::function` is that the function type and arguments pass `std::is_invokable` which is [not the case here](https://godbolt.org/z/Yc3Tj3fGW)

Comment: @PeterT can you point me to a reference? I didnt find that information. Meanwhile there is an answer that correctly explains why OPs code fails, but your comment made me curious and I found that its not just the constructor https://godbolt.org/z/6qooa6o3h (note: different example where the answer does not apply)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the answer makes the same point, one of the requirements for [`Callable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) is basically `is_invocable`

Comment: @PeterT the answer says "issue is the fact that std::function<> templated constructor (one which would be called when std::function is created from the lambda) is SFINAE-restricted on object being Callable with types of arguments provided." In my example I am not calling that constructor

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number oh, I'm not sure if that's exactly specified anywhere. But it would be rather weird to have std::function object that can only ever throw bad_function_call and not do anything else.

Comment: @PeterT anyhow, I found the place where it is mentioned on cppref. I just missed that before. Maybe I'll also look it up in the standard.

Comment: You *can* use `t&&` for the lambda argument though. Magic of type erasure and all that. The signatures don't have to match verbatim, just be "compatible". Problem is of course that... you still can't invoke `func` at all, unless it's the same way you invoke the lambda, with a prvalue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The diagnostic is super misleading. While it is obvious that mutex is not copyable, there is no copying of mutex requested in the provided snippet!

The immediate cause of issue is the fact that `std::function<>` templated constructor (one which would be called when `std::function` is created from the lambda) is [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error)-restricted on object being [`Callable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable) with types of arguments provided.

`Callable` is not satisfied, since the calling expression tries to pass mutex by value, and mutex is not copyable.

As a result, compiler can't find any suitable constructor to construct the `std::function` object and issues diagnostic observed.

It also seems the inability to construct an `std::function` like that is somewhat unfortunate, since you would be able to call a normal function or lambda with temporary-constructed object like

```
f(t{});
```

due to guaranteed copy elision. While it makes no sense to do so for `std::mutex`, it could be meaningful for other non-copyable, non-movable classes.

Comment: this is exactly the detail I was looking for that I didnt find :) Its a little strange that the lambda is not considered a Callable. On the other hand, it is only a weird corner case that can be invoked

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it seems like a quality of implementation issue. It is not immediately obvious to me if it can be easily fixed, though.

Comment: i guess Callable is just right. Even if one could construct this `std::function` I don't think it is possible to call it. Then its a matter of choice where to put the surprise and failing on construction is probably the better

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I would imagine you should be able to call it with temporary-constructed mutex like in your example (due to guaranteed copy elision)

Comment: @SergeyA I don't believe they can since `std::function::operator()` takes by value, so it would try to make a copy when it forwards the mutex to the closure.

Comment: The types in `Args` will only be a reference type if that is how it is for the `std::funtion`.  `std::function<void(t)>` doesn't take by reference, so `operator()` wont either.

Comment: @NathanOliver yep, I agree with you.

Comment: @NathanOliver - Actually... a quirk of `std::forward` makes it so it will pass the argument on as a `t&&`. So a lambda accepting by rvalue reference [would work](https://godbolt.org/z/G1xcWe55n)... But I don't know how useful it'd be to have a `func` that is only invocable with prvalues.

Comment: @SergeyA, thanks! I have one more interrogation: after fixing the mutex issue, why adding a copy constructor to this class makes the compilation fail again? [https://godbolt.org/z/oWcM1jE77](https://godbolt.org/z/oWcM1jE77)

Comment: @Victor: you have two issues in your snippet, one, copy constructor signature should be `t(const t& )`, second, your constructor is private. After fixing those it works as expected: https://godbolt.org/z/Wzdc6GhEz