# Conversion to std::function fails from a function receiving a class with a non-copyable member variable and an explicitly-declared destructor by value

Tags: c++, stl

Note: this is a variation of [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68379058/why-cant-i-convert-a-lambda-with-a-non-copyable-class-parameter-to-a-stdfunct), but with a movable object and a explicitly declared destructor.

The following code

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

struct S
{
    ~S();
    std::unique_ptr<int> x;
};

std::function<void(S)> x = [](S){};
```

fails to compile:

```
<source>:11:28: error: conversion from '<lambda(S)>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<void(S)>' requested
   11 | std::function<void(S)> x = [](S){};
      |
```

It compiles as expected if I either:

1. remove the explicit destructor declaration
2. remove the `x` member variable;
3. use `const S&` instead of `S`.

Why is that and why does explicitly declaring `~S` matter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`S` isn't copyable, because `std::unique_ptr` isn't copyable.

`S` also isn't movable, because a user declaration of a destructor prevents the move operations from being implicitly declared. You would have to declare (and default/define) them manually.

Generally, the rule-of-five should be followed: If you declare a destructor, then you should also declare and default/delete/define all copy/move constructors/assignment operators. However, whenever functionally possible avoid declaring *any* of them (rule-of-zero).

Then `std::function<void(S)>` can't viably be used with the lambda, because `operator()` of `std::function<void(S)>` takes an `S` as parameter and would require a move-construction of the `S` parameter of the lambda from its own `S` when forwarding to it. Therefore the construction of the `std::function<void(S)>` from the lambda is prohibited.

Using `const S&` instead of `S` in the lambda works, because then there is no parameter object that must be move-constructed and invoking the lambda with an `S` rvalue from `std::function<void(S)>::operator()` will be valid.

Comment: "a user declaration of a destructor prevents the move operations from being implicitly declared": this is what I was missing. Thank you.